# Facebook OpenID Selector

Tags: authentication-authorization

I work with the OpenID Selector; everything is OK, but nothing happens when I click on "Facebook."

I work with the [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module; this works fine, but with the OpenID Selector just it's just select the facebook icon.
Another issue is when a user log in to my website and needs to log out; the user is still logged in with the service he used.

Comment: Hello, Sami Ghname; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. What you report seems a bug of the module; if that is the case, then you should report it in the issue queue for the module. _Drupal Answers_ doesn't replace any project issue queue, and the correct place to report a bug is Drupal.org.

Comment: It's not then clear to me what you mean with "but with the OpenID Selector just it's just select the facebook icon."

Comment: I mean when need to log in with the Facebook i click on the Facebook icon but nothing happen just it's select this icon and still on the same page.

Thanks for your reply. 

i report this bug on the module but not any one ask me and another user have the same bug this link for the bug page http://drupal.org/node/1025038

Answer (score 2):

From the libraries/openid-selector/README.txt:

> 1. how to plug-in facebook provider
>      put the following code in providers_large or providers_small:

```
facebook = {
     name: 'Facebook',
     url: "javascript:facebook_click();"
}
```

> where facebook_click is something like:

```
function facebook_click() {
      $('#<id of html fbconnect element>').click();
}
```

> the same mechanism also applies if you want to plug-in any oauth or xauth provider

So that is what the README says. I specifically had to do the following I'm using Drupal7.8 with openid-selector module 7.x-3.x (2011 May 07):

In modules/openid_selector/openid_selector_fb.js:
Replace the chunks that look like similar with the ones Ive posted.

```
providers_large.facebook = {
  name: 'Facebook',
  url: "javascript: $('.fb_button').click();"
};
```

and again for this chunk

```
Drupal.behaviors.openid_selector_fb = { attach: function (context) {
  $('.fb_user-login-button-wrapper').hide();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make use of the facebook Like button source code. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ use this link to get the source code and put them in your template file. I am not sure it may help you or not, but still this method fixed my problem once.